# download Ubuntu to new clean SSD

Tags: ssd

My old Acer computers (windows 7) have crashed and I can't boot up to do anything. I've accepted that I've messed up and probably lost all my files, but this prompts me to convert to Ubuntu as I've intended to do for many months.    I have a new clean SSD.   Can I download Ubuntu to a micro on my tablet and then transfer the card to the laptop and get an operating system going that way?   It's probably obvious that I'm less than informed or competent so I would very much appreciate detailed instructions geared to a 4 yr old,  or perhaps a 94 yr old, or a not very intelligent dog. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're new to Ubuntu, I'll recommend you take look at this up-to-date installation instructions. When you visit the learn, take some minutes of your time to *actually* read: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: "_probably lost all my files_" - you've _probably not_ lost all your files. I'm pretty sure they're still there on the hard drive, unless you deleted them or the hard drive is broken - you can recover them fairly easily with an Ubuntu live USB or DVD, or by getting a USB enclosure for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to another computer, then your tablet should be also fine. You will need the application DriveDroid on GooglePlay. Be careful, it requires a rooted Android device! (e.g. your tablet).

[DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) allows you to boot your PC from ISO/IMG files stored on your phone. This is ideal for trying Linux distributions or always having a rescue-system on the go... without the need to burn different CDs or USB pendrives.

The installation way is following:

1. You download and install Drivedroid on your tablet.
2. You launch the Drivedroid and download the Ubuntu distribution - Ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso will be fine. The file is large, so be prepared with your power supply for the tablet and a good internet connection.
3. Install your SSD disk into the computer.
4. Once downloaded tap on the downloaded image in the Drivedroid.
   Tap host image and Writeable USB.
5. Attach the USB cable from tablet to the computer.
6. Boot the computer from USB - you need to setup this in the BIOS of your computer.
7. The computer should boot into Live USB and you can choose the Ubuntu installation.